# How to add values into a list from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to add values into a list from a database?
I would like to validate 2 models in 1 single view  index.cshtml using the following code but I don't know how to get values from a database :

How to add values into a list from a database?
I would like to validate 2 models in 1 single view  index.cshtml using the following code but I don't know how to get values from a database :

How to add values into a list from a database?
I would like to validate 2 models in 1 single view  index.cshtml using the following code but I don't know how to get values from a database :

How to add values into a list from a database?
I would like to validate 2 models in 1 single view  index.cshtml using the following code but I don't know how to get values from a database :

```
                @*@model List<BrandonMifsud2021NotificationSystem.Models.tbl_notification>*@
                @using BrandonMifsud2021NotificationSystem.Models;
                @model MainPageModel


                @{
                    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
                }



                @foreach (var b in Model.tbl_Notification)
                {

                <p>@b.notificationText </p>

                }

                @foreach (var b in Model.tbl_User_Notification)
                {
                    <p>@b.userName</p>

                }



                public ActionResult Index()
                        {




        



                            List<tbl_notification> lstNotifications = new 
                            List<tbl_notification>();
                            lstNotifications.Add(new tbl_notification());
                            List<tbl_user_notification> lstUserNotifications = new 
                            List<tbl_user_notification>();
                            lstUserNotifications.Add(new tbl_user_notification());

                            MainPageModel objMainViewModel = new MainPageModel();
                            objMainViewModel.tbl_Notification = lstNotifications;
                            objMainViewModel.tbl_User_Notification = lstUserNotifications;

                            return View(objMainViewModel);






                            
                        }
```

Comment: Please don't write a poor quality question with too much code and not enough words, hit the automated "your question needs more words" check trying to prevent you submit your poor quality question, and defeat it by copypasta'ing the same poor quality wording over and over

Comment: Your question is off topic because it lacks focus/it is too broad. There are plenty of tutorials out there that will assist you wil a c# flavored "connect to db, download data into a list" - it's not concise enough to be answerable here

Comment: I need to add values into  lstNotifications.Add(new tbl_notification()); get values from database not like this 
List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
    teachers.Add(new Teacher { TeacherId = 1, Code = "TT", Name = "Tejas Trivedi" });

Comment: Is it concise enough to be answerable now, please?

Comment: I think you might have overlooked the presence of the edit button.. I must apologize if my use of the word "concise" was misleading; by "concise" I meant "the problem must be very focused" not "use fewer words". Here is an example of an unfocused, non-concise problem; "I need an air traffic control system. Please write my air traffic control system for me"

Comment: My issue is with lstNotifications.Add(new tbl_notification()); I need to get values from database. Similar to this List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
    teachers.Add(new Teacher { TeacherId = 1, Code = "TT", Name = "Tejas Trivedi" }); but getting values from db not hardcoded values.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the problem; as I've said, it isn't something we can help with because it's too much code for us to write. Go and find a C# tutorial for your database, write some code and come ask us a question if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

View take a one model. You create DTO or viewmodel for view. OR you dont want to write dto or viewmodel you use tuple.

Tuple example for view:
@model Tuple<model1,model2>

Comment: My issue is with lstNotifications.Add(new tbl_notification()); I need to get values from database. Similar to this but getting values from db not hardcoded values